# How to add new box with size of the last box

Tags: javascript, function, dom-events

I have a problem with adding a function which will create an amount of boxes with rising size and when i try to add more I will start from the size of the previous last box.

So far i have a code like this:

```
function getRandomHexColor() {
    return `#${Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16)}`;
}
const input = document.querySelector("#controls>input");
const createBtn = document.querySelector("button[data-create]");
const destroyBtn = document.querySelector("button[data-destroy]");
const boxCollection = document.querySelector("#boxes");

const createBoxes = (amount) => {
    amount = input.value;
    for (let i = 0; i < amount; i += 1) {
        let newBox = document.createElement("div");
        newBox.style.height = `${30 + 10 * i}px`;
        newBox.style.width = `${30 + 10 * i}px`;
        newBox.style.background = getRandomHexColor();
        boxCollection.insertAdjacentElement("beforeend", newBox);
    }
};

createBtn.addEventListener("click", createBoxes);

const destroyBoxes = () => {
    boxCollection.innerHTML = "";
};

destroyBtn.addEventListener("click", destroyBoxes);
```

I was thinking about adding a new `var` which will be the `lastChild` of `const boxCollection` and add it to height and width of newBox. Am I thinking right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either create a variable with the current number of boxes or you can just count the current number each time you add more. In the example the current number (`currentCount`) is based on the length of a querySelectorAll().

```js
function getRandomHexColor() {
  return `#${Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16)}`;
}

const boxCollection = document.querySelector("#boxes");

const createBoxes = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let amount = parseInt(e.target.amount.value);
  let currentCount = boxCollection.querySelectorAll('div').length;
  Object.keys([...Array(amount)]).forEach(i => {
    let incVal = parseInt(i) + currentCount;
    let newBox = document.createElement("div");
    newBox.style.height = `${30 + 10 * incVal}px`;
    newBox.style.width = `${30 + 10 * incVal}px`;
    newBox.style.background = getRandomHexColor();
    boxCollection.insertAdjacentElement("beforeend", newBox);
  });
};

const destroyBoxes = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  boxCollection.innerHTML = "";
};

document.forms.create.addEventListener("submit", createBoxes);
document.forms.destroy.addEventListener("submit", destroyBoxes);
```

```html
<form name="create">
  <input type="number" name="amount" />
  <button>Create</button>
</form>
<form name="destroy">
  <button>Destroy</button>
</form>
<div id="boxes"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I've looking for

Answer (score 0):

You could hold the latest size of the box in a var.

```
function getRandomHexColor() {
    return `#${Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16)}`;
}
const input = document.querySelector("#controls>input");
const createBtn = document.querySelector("button[data-create]");
const destroyBtn = document.querySelector("button[data-destroy]");
const boxCollection = document.querySelector("#boxes");

let currentBoxSize = 30        // starting box size
const BOX_SIZE_INCREMENT = 10  // increment size

const createBoxes = (amount) => {
    amount = input.value;
    for (let i = 0; i < amount; i += 1) {
        let newBox = document.createElement("div");
        newBox.style.height = `${currentBoxSize}px`;
        newBox.style.width = `${currentBoxSize}px`;
        newBox.style.background = getRandomHexColor();
        boxCollection.insertAdjacentElement("beforeend", newBox);

        currentBoxSize += BOX_SIZE_INCREMENT
    }
};

createBtn.addEventListener("click", createBoxes);

const destroyBoxes = () => {
    boxCollection.innerHTML = "";
};

destroyBtn.addEventListener("click", destroyBoxes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just store the last `input` value in a variable, or if you want to preserve the state, you can store it in locale storage, and when you click create boxes, `sum` it with the value with the new `input` value.

```
function getRandomHexColor() {
    return `#${Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16)}`;
}
const input = document.querySelector("#controls>input");
const createBtn = document.querySelector("button[data-create]");
const destroyBtn = document.querySelector("button[data-destroy]");
const boxCollection = document.querySelector("#boxes");
let lastInputValue = 0;

const createBoxes = (amount) => {
    amount = input.value + lastInputValue;
    for (let i = 0; i < amount; i += 1) {
        let newBox = document.createElement("div");
        newBox.style.height = `${30 + 10 * i}px`;
        newBox.style.width = `${30 + 10 * i}px`;
        newBox.style.background = getRandomHexColor();
        boxCollection.insertAdjacentElement("beforeend", newBox);
    }
    lastInputValue = amount;
};

createBtn.addEventListener("click", createBoxes);

const destroyBoxes = () => {
    boxCollection.innerHTML = "";
};

destroyBtn.addEventListener("click", destroyBoxes);
```